# ReferenceError: FontFaceObserver is not defined

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I've checked some of the other ReferenceError questions but they don't seem to have an applicable answer.

I'm using [FontFaceObserver](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) to load web fonts, so I've added that file to my page:

```
<script src='js/fontfaceobserver.min.js' async></script>
```

After that script, I have another script with the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var BitterRegular = new FontFaceObserver('BitterRegular', {
    weight: 400
  })
});
```

The page isn't loading the web fonts. The exception being thrown in Firefox is `ReferenceError: FontFaceObserver is not defined`. I've tried the basics:

```
var ffo = new FontFaceObserver();
var BitterRegular = ffo('BitterRegular', {
  weight: 400
})
```

However, that doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas about what I might be able to do to get around this exception? Thanks!

Comment: Have you used `"strict mode";`?

Comment: Yes, I've used that but doesn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the async from the script tag. Loading FontFaceObserver asynchronously may result in the script requiring it to miss and throw Reference error